# error using align and \crefrange in same equation

Tags: equations, errors, align

I'm new to Latex family and need some help.

I get a list of errors when I use `\crefrange` within the `align` environment.

For example

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{align}
\min &\left(
\underbrace{\sum\limits_{t \in T} 
\left(\mathcal{Q}^{+}_{t} \pi^{+}_{t} - \mathcal{Q}^{-}_{t} \pi^{-}_{t} \right) 
\Delta t}_\text{electricity cost} 
+ \underbrace{\sum\limits_{t \in T} \sum\limits_{b \in B} 
\partial_{(t,b)}}_\text{degradation penalty} \right) 
\label{base1} \\
\st \notag \\
&\mathcal{Q}^{+}_{t} - \mathcal{Q}^{-}_{t} = \mathcal{P}^{L}_{t} 
+ \sum\limits_{b \in B} \mathcal{P}^{c}_{(t,b)} 
- \mathcal{P}^{K}_{t} \label{base2} \\
&\Crefrange{eq_Ch4_soc1}{eq_Ch4_deg2}, 
 \crefrange{eq_Ch4_opt4}{eq_Ch4_opt6} \notag \\
&\Crefrange{eq_Ch4_power3}{eq_Ch4_power5} \label{base3}
\end{align}
```

When I comment out (exclude) this portion of the article, LaTeX processes the complete article without error.

I do have `align` equations in other locations of the article, but it does not encounter any error with those equations as those equations do not have `\crefrange` in them.

below is the list of errors that appear when I run the code:

```
Use of \refstepcounter@optarg doesn't match its definition. \end{align}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \cref@stack@to@list has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \cref@stack@to@list was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \cref@stack@to@list has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \cref@stack@to@list was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \cref@stack@to@list has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \cref@stack@to@list was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \cref@stack@to@list has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \cref@stack@to@list was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{align}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{align}
Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete. \end{align}
Use of \@@cref@getlabel doesn't match its definition. \end{align}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{align}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{align}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete. \end{align}
Use of \@@cref@gettype doesn't match its definition. \end{align}
Argument of \@@cref@gettype has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \@@cref@gettype was complete. \end{align}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \@crefrangenostar has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \@crefrangenostar was complete. \end{align}
Argument of \@crefrangenostar has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \@crefrangenostar was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \cref@stack@to@list has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \cref@stack@to@list was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \cref@stack@to@list has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \cref@stack@to@list was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \label@noarg has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \label@noarg was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Extra \else. \end{align}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{align}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \cref@stack@to@list has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \cref@stack@to@list was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \cref@stack@to@list has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \cref@stack@to@list was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete. \end{align}
Use of \@@cref@gettype doesn't match its definition. \end{align}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \@crefrangenostar has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \@crefrangenostar was complete. \end{align}
Argument of \@crefrangenostar has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \@crefrangenostar was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \cref@stack@to@list has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \cref@stack@to@list was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Argument of \cref@stack@to@list has an extra }. \end{align}
Paragraph ended before \cref@stack@to@list was complete. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What the the `\Crefrange` instructions doing *inside* an equation? And how is `\st` defined?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what the `\crefrange` and `\Crefrange` directives are doing inside a multi-line equation. I'm pretty sure that cross-referencing should almost invariably be done in text mode, not math mode.

I would also comment out (or delete) the line that contains an otherwise-undefined macro called `st`.

A separate comment: I would use `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`, *not* `\left(` and `\right`, to size the large parentheses in the first row. Oh, and none of the `\limits` directives do anything but create code clutter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \min &\biggl(\,
    \underbrace{\sum_{t\in T} (\mathcal{Q}^{+}_t \pi^{+}_t 
         - \mathcal{Q}^{-}_t \pi^{-}_t ) \Delta t}
         _{\text{electricity cost}}
  + \underbrace{\sum_{t\in T} \sum_{b\in B} \partial_{(t,b)}}
         _{\mathclap{\text{degradation penalty}}}\!
    \biggr) \label{base1} \\[1ex]
%    \st \notag \\  % how is `\st` defined?
    &\mathcal{Q}^{+}_t - \mathcal{Q}^{-}_t 
      = \mathcal{P}^{L}_t + \sum_{b\in B} \mathcal{P}^{c}_{(t,b)} 
       -\mathcal{P}^{K}_t \label{base2} 
%    \\
%    &\Crefrange{eq_Ch4_soc1}{eq_Ch4_deg2}, \crefrange{eq_Ch4_opt4}{eq_Ch4_opt6} \notag \\
%    &\Crefrange{eq_Ch4_power3}{eq_Ch4_power5} \label{base3}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```